# How to go back to the first screen of iPhone App on Log Out?

Tags: swift, ios8, heap-memory, xcode6.1

I have an app whose structure is defined in the attached image.

Basically, I have a Sign In View Controller as the Root View Controller. When user signs in, app they go to the `TabbarController`, from where they go to the Home View Controller. And there are three more tabs. Now there is a <kbd>Log Out</kbd> Button tapping on which user should go to the Sign In View Controller but if I write code to pop to Root View Controller they will go to the Root View Controller of any tab but not on the Sign In Screen.

[image]

How can I POP to the Sign In View Controller?

I don't want to create new Object of `SignInViewController` so Push won't work for me and moreover, it will cost lots of memory.

I am using Swift in Xcode 6.1

Comment: You can use an unwind segue. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: you can use ' [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:True]'

Comment: @Ashok Please see this line I have mentioned in my question.-------
"if I write code to pop to Root View Controller to he will go to the Root View Controller of any tab but not on the Sign In Screen. -----"

Comment: In which View Controller you have embedded Navigation Controller.

Comment: and i think your RootViewController is SignScreenViewController

Comment: what is the `SingInViewController` exactly? a navigation-controller? a view-controller?

Comment: @holex Here is the image of SignInViewController, how I have integrated!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ymnz12oibujxk0/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-18%20at%205.08.11%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @SurgePedroza Yes, I found the solution.
I created one global object of Navigation Controller and assigned it to the object of Navigation Controller in SignInViewController.
Then I called pushToViewController: and passed that global object.
Let me know if you still have any doubt! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You must have to make SignInViewController as a root view controller.

1. delete the login credentials.
2. and load the SignInViewController as a rootviewcontroller.

NOTE: in my scenario workflow will work best in ARC mode. because in ARC mode we don't have to release all view controllers you have loaded in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of changing rootviewcontroller with animation. This method defined in AppDelegate class. Do not forget to assign storyboardid to your desired ViewController.

```
 - (void)changeRootViewControllerWithID:(NSString *)storyboardId
    {
        UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController * newRootViewController = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];

        [newRootViewController view];

        [UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                                                toView:newRootViewController.view
                                            duration:0.65f
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        self.window.rootViewController = newRootViewController;
                                        }];

    }
```